# Get all nodes with given type by ( select * from tablename in SQL world) with Cypher Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am very new to Neo4j just learn it from last Friday.

I wonder if how can we get all nodes with the same type for example.
I want to create page that list all users in the system.

My idea now have two approach:
1  Cypher with where clause:

```
CYPHER 2.0  START n=node(*) 
WHERE n.type = 'user' 
RETURN n
```

2 Cypher with indexing on type property

```
START n=node:userindex(type = 'user') RETURN n
```

I know that if userindex contains only user value for key type, it is not selective and is not good for indexing.

I don't know which one is the best approach for this since all example I found mostly start with 
one or two node and begin find other nodes that have relation with start node.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use [labels](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels) for this. This could be your query:

```
MATCH (user:User)
RETURN user;
```

Answer (score 1):

Full example using Neo4j v2.1.0

```
CREATE (n:Person { name: "Tim" });
CREATE (n:Animal { name: "Tom" });

START m=node(*)                    RETURN m;
+---------------------+
| m                   |
+---------------------+
| Node[0]{name:"Tim"} |
| Node[1]{name:"Tom"} |
+---------------------+

START m=node(*)  MATCH (m:Person)  RETURN m;
+---------------------+
| m                   |
+---------------------+
| Node[0]{name:"Tim"} |
+---------------------+

START m=node(*)  MATCH (m:Animal)  RETURN m;
+---------------------+
| m                   |
+---------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"Tom"} |
+---------------------+

START m=node(*)                    RETURN m, labels(m);
+----------------------------------+
| m                   | labels(m)  |
+----------------------------------+
| Node[0]{name:"Tim"} | ["Person"] |
| Node[1]{name:"Tom"} | ["Animal"] |
+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

START n=node(*) 
WHERE HAS(n.type) AND n.type = 'user' 
RETURN n

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all users in your `userindex`, then use:

```
START u=node:userindex("*:*")
RETURN u
```

And to return a list of all user names (assuming each user has the `name` property):

```
START u=node:userindex("*:*")
RETURN u.name as names
```